# how to include (file.form) blade.php file with another blade file in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in my laravel project management application I have project and one project can create many tasks and one task have publish many files regarding to the task. so, in my file attachment form is this in files folder in view file

files/form.blade.php

```
@foreach ($task->project->files as $file)
                <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                        <span>

                            <a href="{{ $file->file_url }}" target="_blank">{{ $file->file_name }}</a>
</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                @endforeach

        <form class="form-vertical" role="form"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                    method="post"
                                    action="{{ route('projects.files', ['projects' => $project->id]) }}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="file" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name">
                @if ($errors->has('file_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('file_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Files</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

and file model relationship with Task model is this

```
public function task(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Task model relationship with File model is this

```
public function files(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\File');
}
```

and now I included files/form.blade.php file with tasks/show.blade.php file as this

tasks/show.blade.php

```
<h2>{{ $task->project->project_name }}</h2>
<hr>

{{$task->task_name}}
<hr>

{!!$task->body!!}

<hr>
@include('files.form')
```

then when I try to view task/show.blade.php file this following error is coming

```
Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: No any idea to fix this problem

Comment: I need some help here

Comment: do you need any more details?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird and shouldn't happen, but try to explicitly pass your variable to your child template:

```
@include('files.form', ['task' => $task])
```

By default, as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views), you should be able to access all data from the parent template in the child template.

Comment: did it but same error here I don't know what is the problem